# How can I do to don't convert index as a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have this dataframe :

```
     type ...
0    a    ...
1    b    ...
2    c    ...
```

And I wanted to keep only the column type so I type this :

```
df = df.iloc[:,0]
```

But the problem is that I lost the name of my column `type`. So to solve this problem I type this :

```
df = df.iloc[:,0].reset_index()
```

And I got the name of my column but the problem is that another column is appear, I mean I got this :

```
     index    type 
0    0        a    
1    1        b    
2    2        c
```

How can I solve this ?

I mean I don't want the column index.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want select one column DataFrame, use nested list `[[0]]`:

```
df = df.iloc[:,[0]]
```